# Import eclipse project with other package name ? - Eclipse / Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have project in eclipse (done app). Now I want copy this project, but with other package name.

I just want do new app, that will have only small changes(some images and database).

How I can import old project with other package name or what should i do in this situation ?

Comment: you can define it as being a library and import it in your new project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Copy project files to new location
2. Import new project
3. Right click on you new project then select -> Android Tools|Rename application package

Comment: Thanks it works :) I aslo find there many other interesing options.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do this in Eclipse....

**1.** File --> Import

**2.** File --> New Android Project --> Give path for the Project to be imported

Now `R_CLick on the Package from the Package Explorer --> then goto Refactor --> New name`